# Ember setting up routes to get associated data from rails api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an Ember app setup that gets it's data from a Rails API. I have routes setup right now that work, but not how I'm wanting. The current route structure (for the ember app) is this:

```
//router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('surveys');
  this.route('survey', { path: 'surveys/:survey_id' }, function() {
    this.route('sections', { path: '/sections' });
  });

  this.route('section', {path: 'surveys/:survey_id/sections/:section_id'}, function() {
    this.route('survey_items', { path: 'survey-items' });
  });

});
```

In the models I have surveys, and each survey has many sections, and each section has many survey items. The way it's setup now kinda work, but my sticking point is, if I go to the `section` route I want to have a "next" button that when you click it, it takes you to the next section in that survey. Right now I can't make that happen correctly, because my `section` route loads the model by just finding the section by the passed in id param. If all of the sections for all surveys are loaded in the store already and I increment the section right now, it goes to the next section regardless of which survey_id it is associated with. I can't figure out how to setup my routes better to make this work.

The rails api routes look like this right now:

```
routes.rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :surveys, shallow:true do
      resources :sections, shallow: true do
        resources :survey_items, path: '/survey-items'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, in the Rails routes I put `shallow: true` on the `surveys` and `sections` resources. For some reason, when I had them nested without shallow routes, I couldn't get ember to load the proper route without nesting my ember routes, which nests the UI, which I don't want. Can anyone give me any tips on how I can setup my routes without needing shallow routes in rails (if possible) and how I should be getting the model data for each section so the I can go to the next section in the associated survey?

The current routes model for `section` is fetched like this currently:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('section', params.section_id, { reload: true });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about setting shallow: true in your routes.rb file. However, for the UI, I would use Ember Data's `hasMany` method on the `survey` model.

```
// survey.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  sections: DS.hasMany('section')
});
```

If you serialize a `links` property when fetching the survey, you can direct the `hasMany` to a specific endpoint in your API, and just handle scoping the sections to that specific survey in that controller. An example of how to serialize the `links` attribute on your `SurveySerializer` (assuming you are using ActiveModelSerializers):

```
def links
  {
    sections: api_v1_survey_sections_path
  }
end
```

Then in your `sections` route in the UI, I would return just those survey's sections in your model hook:

```
// sections.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var survey = this.modelFor('survey');

    return survey.get('sections');
  }
});
```

I would put the `link-to` for the `section` route in your `sections` template. The `sections` controller will manage what id or model you will pass to its dynamic segment based on what is 'next'. Passing a model probably would make sense rather than an id so the `section` model hook would be skipped.

Lastly, is there any reason that you didn't write your routes in your `router.js` file like this?

```
// router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('surveys');
  this.route('survey', { path: 'surveys/:survey_id' }, function() {
    this.route('sections', function() {
      this.route('section', {path: ':section_id'}, function() {
        this.route('survey_items', { path: 'survey-items' });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's definitely the most helpful info I've found on this so far. As for the router.js routes, I didn't write them like that because those routes aren't nested in the UI. There is individual pages for showing the initial survey details, and all the sections in the survey, and then individual pages for each section so the routes can't be nested or the UI get's nested from my understanding.